# None of the 'rake' commands works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, backend

I received working application built in ruby on rails and react.js and i have problem with running server on ruby.
That's what have I done:

1. ruby 3.1.2,
2. rails 5.1.2,
3. gem 3.3.7,
4. with blunder I installed all
   dependecies,
5. I also changed config in database.yml.

Whatever I do I only see this errors:

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/devise-jwt-0.8.1/lib/devise/jwt.rb:29:in `<module:Devise>' [dry-configurable] default value as positional argument to settings is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version
Provide a `default:` keyword argument instead
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/devise-jwt-0.8.1/lib/devise/jwt.rb:29:in `<module:Devise>' [dry-configurable] passing a constructor as a block is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version
Provide a `constructor:` keyword argument instead
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
C:/Users/Wojciech Kowalczyk/Desktop/java_script/zadanie_rekrutacyjne/testowe 2/backend/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

That's how the jwt.rb file looks like:

```
require 'forwardable'
require 'devise'
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors'
require 'warden/jwt_auth'
require 'devise/jwt/version'
require 'devise/jwt/mapping_inspector'
require 'devise/jwt/defaults_generator'
require 'devise/jwt/railtie'
require 'devise/jwt/models'
require 'devise/jwt/revocation_strategies'
require 'dry-configurable'

# Authentication library
module Devise
  # Yields to Warden::JWTAuth.config
  #
  # @see Warden::JWTAuth
  def self.jwt
    Warden::JWTAuth.config.to_h
    yield(Devise::JWT.config)
    Devise::JWT.config.to_h
  end

  add_module(:jwt_authenticatable, strategy: :jwt)

  # JWT extension for devise
  module JWT
    extend Dry::Configurable

    def self.forward_to_warden(setting, value)
      default = Warden::JWTAuth.config.send(setting)
      Warden::JWTAuth.config.send("#{setting}=", value || default)
      Warden::JWTAuth.config.send(setting)
    end

    setting(:secret, Warden::JWTAuth.config.secret) do |value|
      forward_to_warden(:secret, value)
    end

    setting(:expiration_time, Warden::JWTAuth.config.expiration_time) do |value|
      forward_to_warden(:expiration_time, value)
    end

    setting(:dispatch_requests,
            Warden::JWTAuth.config.dispatch_requests) do |value|
      forward_to_warden(:dispatch_requests, value)
    end

    setting(:revocation_requests,
            Warden::JWTAuth.config.revocation_requests) do |value|
      forward_to_warden(:revocation_requests, value)
    end

    setting(:aud_header, Warden::JWTAuth.config.aud_header) do |value|
      forward_to_warden(:aud_header, value)
    end

    # A hash of warden scopes as keys and an array of request formats that will
    # be processed as values. When a scope is not present or if it has a nil
    # item, requests without format will be taken into account.
    #
    # For example, with following configuration, `user` scope would dispatch and
    # revoke tokens in `json` requests, while `admin_user` would do it in `xml`
    # and with no format.
    #
    # @example
    # {
    #   user: [:json],
    #   admin_user: [nil, :xml]
    # }
    setting :request_formats, {}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So, steps to do here:

1. Go to [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/) and search for the gem to see if there's a later version.
2. There is in this case, so then go to [the gem's github page](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt) and take a look in the changelog if they have one (or resolved issues if not).
3. This gem [does have a changelog](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), so then take a look at the changes since the version you're using and see if (a) there are no breaking changes and (b) if anything sounds like it might be relevant to the problem you're seeing.
4. If both of those things are true then try upgrading the gem to the latest version.